# Name for phrase only understood by those who already know?

Tags: terminology

I'm having a hard time thinking of an example, except I remember someone making a recursive joke about it once. They explained the meaning of it by using its definition, hence the joke. Something like "An *X* is only an *X* for those who already know".

What is the name for this kind of phrase?

Comment: Your question is severely underspecified.

Comment: @JimBalter not necessarily undespecified. If you knew what he is talking about you'd know what he is talking about.

Comment: @MattThomas actually my [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379285/name-for-phrase-only-understood-by-those-who-already-know?noredirect=1#comment892611_379285) was a recursive joke based on your own question.

Comment: Don't post answers in the comments.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**shibboleth**

noun

2. a custom, phrase, or use of language that acts as a test of belonging to, or as a stumbling block to becoming a member of, a particular social class, profession, etc

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shibboleth)

Today, in American English, a shibboleth also has a wider meaning, referring to any "in-group" word or phrase that can be used to distinguish members of a group from outsiders – even when not used by a hostile other group

Probably not what you're looking for, but a fun word nonetheless.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56018/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-elliott-name-for-phrase-only-understood-by-those-who).

Answer (score 27):

**esoteric**

adjective

1.
understood by or meant for only the select few who have special knowledge or interest; recondite:

2.
belonging to the select few.

3.
private; secret; confidential.

4.
(of a philosophical doctrine or the like) intended to be revealed only to the initiates of a group

Comment: I don't think this is the word I was looking for, but it probably answers my question (as worded) best. Thanks

Comment: The community voted. Sorry, Ricky, but I think I need to [change accepted answers](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2650/226140)

Comment: Sometimes the community is wrong (actually, it is probably right in this case, but I believe esoteric would be easier to understand in most cases where the readers may not be "in the know").

Answer (score 26):

The question in your title doesn't really match what's asked in the body of your question. But a possible answer to the question in your title is **[jargon](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jargon)**.

> special words and phrases that are used by particular groups of
>   people, especially in their work

The [Wikipedia entry for jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon) adds to this by saying

> The main trait that distinguishes jargon from the rest of a language
>   is special vocabulary—including some words specific to it and, often,
>   narrower senses of words that outgroups would tend to take in a
>   broader sense.

In other words, jargon can include words whose meaning within a group is quite different than the meaning outside that group.

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps you are remembering the somewhat recent use of the term [***dog-whistle***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dog_whistle). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> 1.1 *usually as modifier* A subtly aimed political message which is intended for, and can only be understood by, a particular demographic group.

There's a fair bit of discussion about the origin of this particular usage in [this EL&U question and its answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342326/meaning-and-origin-of-dog-whistle-e-g-trumps-assassination-dog-whistle). (Essentially, it's a metaphor from actual dog whistles, which are so high-pitched that only dogs can hear them, originally applied to politics in Australia and very quickly adopted throughout the English-speaking world.) This phrase came up a lot during the recent political turmoil in the UK and US.

Comment: I actually haven't heard the term before—thanks for the new phrase!

Comment: @MattThomas One can infer that you don't read liberal political commentary.

Comment: @JimBalter These days my head is mostly buried in software and technical documentation :|

Answer (score 9):

In the 19th century, the parlance of criminals in the UK would be termed **argot**, the word is less popular these days but still relevant and has a broader usage.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot) defines it as:

> An argot (English pronunciation: /ˈɑːrɡoʊ/; from French argot [aʁˈɡo]
>   'slang') is a secret language used by various groups—e.g.,
>   schoolmates, outlaws, colleagues, among many others—to prevent
>   outsiders from understanding their conversations. The term argot is
>   also used to refer to the informal specialized vocabulary from a
>   particular field of study, occupation, or hobby, in which sense it
>   overlaps with jargon.

Answer (score 4):

### term of art

> noun
>
> a word or phrase that has a specific or precise meaning within a given
>   discipline or field and might have a different meaning in common
>   usage:
>
> *Set is a term of art used by mathematicians, and burden of proof is a term of art used by lawyers.*
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/term-of-art

You could make a self-referential joke like this for example:

*"Term of art" is a term of art in the legal profession.*

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is **self-referential**, and you're indicating a case of [**self-referential humor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-referential_humor).

> Self-referential humor or self-reflexive humor is a type of comedic expression[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-referential_humor) that—either directed toward some other subject, or openly directed toward itself—intentionally alludes to the very person who is expressing the humor in a comedic fashion, or to some specific aspect of that same comedic expression.

These are variants of Hofstadter's famous [*recursive-acronym*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym), which is very influential in the computer-science domain. For instance, GNU is a recursive acronym for [*GNU's Not Unix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU).

Comment: My attempted example was definitely self-referential, but this doesn't quite fit: self-reference does not imply a lack of understanding

Comment: Ah, okay, I missed the point of that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about a [**code name**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/code-name) (sometimes **code word** or **code phrase**):

> 2. Also called *code phrase*. a word or phrase assigned a meaning understood only by those who are secretly informed of it.

Popular in spy movies, these are words or phrases that sound otherwise innocuous, but indicate to the listener that you are "in the know".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the situation you're describing is a circular definition. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_definition)

> A circular definition is one that uses the term(s) being defined as a part of the definition or assumes a prior understanding of the term being defined.

And, long-shot, but maybe you were talking about an "autological word" [wikipedia again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)

> An autological word (also called homological word or autonym) is a word that expresses a property that it also possesses (e.g. the word "short" is short, "noun" is a noun, "English" is English, "pentasyllabic" has five syllables, "word" is a word).

Answer (score 0):

Tautology

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tautology

> 1. needless repetition of an idea, especially in words other than those of the immediate context, without imparting additional force or clearness, as in “widow woman.”.
> 2. an instance of such repetition.
> 3. Logic.
>    a compound propositional form all of whose instances are true, as “A or not A.”.
>    an instance of such a form, as “This candidate will win or will not win.”.

Comment: Not even close.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest it is an instance of Hermetica.  I.e. in the sense used by Umberto Eco in [Foucault's Pendulum](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17841.Foucault_s_Pendulum).

The Hermetica are Egyptian-Greek wisdom texts from the 2nd and 3rd centuries AD, which are mostly presented as dialogues.  Ref [Hermetica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermetica)

So, in Eco's  Foucault's Pendulum, according to an authoritative opinion, 
it's a joke at the expense of the hermetic characters the publishers spend much of their time with, as when it's first used it's about how they literally all have a certain look about them (Lorenza says "professional sorcerers with faces exactly like professional sorcerers", then describes them. Diotallevi quips "Facies hermetica", and from then on it's an in-joke).  Ref [goodreads.com/questions/463533...](http://www.goodreads.com/questions/463533-this-book-uses-the-phrase-facies)

Comment: Please include a definition of this word and describe the sense it is used in in Foucault's Pendulum.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first documented example of the theoretical phenomenon first hinted at by D. Rumsfeld (DR)?

Ref [...there are known knowns etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns)

While the focus for DR was unknown unknowns, this gave a tantalising suggestion of the possible existence of something more esoteric and exotic, an unknown known.  I.e. something where you may or may not have some intuition it exists, but that you cannot detail it with any plausible specificity.

Comment: Unknown knowns are possible. For instance, you might know your neighbor's shoe size but not know that you do because you're unaware that the person whose foot you measured today in your shoe store is your neighbor.